# group by order but found SELECT syntax

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-order-by, inner-join

A select SQL with a subquery that contains a descending sort and inner join to link unto saem id (patid). Once this sort subquery is done I will make it a view query to be used by another SQL which is not working. Using WINSQL with Cache database.

The idea is to sort data_of_assessment in Descending order

```
SELECT c1.patid, c1.date_of_assessment, c1.form_status_value
FROM cw_cans_assessment c1 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * from cw_cans_assessment c2
    ORDER BY c2.data_of_assessement DESC) 
    ON c1.patid = c2.patid
GROUP BY c1.patid
```

Error message:

> [%msg: < ) expected, IDENTIFIER (order) found^SELECT c1 . patid , c1 . date_

Sample Data:

```
patid   date_of_assessment  form_status_value
64050   2009-06-25          Unknown
53297   2011-12-07          Unknown
42308   2016-06-16          Initial
9540757 2016-09-22          Initial
45144   2017-06-23          Reassessment
50529   2017-09-01          Initial
38557   2017-10-17          Initial
52754   2017-10-20          Initial
50123   2017-11-07          Initial
15572   2017-11-14          Initial
```

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  (1) The `GROUP BY` columns do not match the `SELECT` columns.  (2) `c2` is not defined in the outer query.  (3) `ORDER BY` in subqueries is either not supported or a no-op.  (4) You are joining two tables and not using any information from the second one.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation would all help.

Comment: sample data; I do not know how to format data columns here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, what you want is the most recent assessment for each `patid`:

```
select ca.*
from cw_cans_assessment ca
where ca.date_of_assessment = (select max(ca2.date_of_assessment)
                               from cw_cans_assessment ca2
                               where ca2.patid = ca.patid
                              );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c1.patid, c1.date_of_assessment, c1.form_status_value
FROM cw_cans_assessment c1
GROUP BY c1.patid
ORDER BY c1.date_of_assessment
```

I over estimated the problem solution, never should have used the inner join on same table for this turned out to be much simpler solution.